# How do I modify an IF statement in Python to determine motion with only axis data from an ADXL345 accelerometer?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project to use the raspberry pi 2 and an adxl345 accelerometer to detect door motion and sound an alarm upon opening a door that the accelerometer is attached to. The following is the sample of my code that I need help with:

```
axes = adxl345.getAxes(True)
if axes['z'] >= 0: 
    print "Intruder Detected"
```

I already have a seperate python file that outputs the readings from the x, y, and z axes as Gs. I am confused about which axis I should be using, or if I should be using a combination of the axis readings to determine the motion of opening a door. Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is the last bit of my project. Thanks!

Comment: It depends which way the door opens. Anyway, it's likely you'll need to attach it and check the readers, and base your algorithm off that.

Comment: My problem is I don't actually know what reading to look for. My physics knowledge isn't that great yet so I'm not very familiar with how the axes work to determine motion.

Comment: That's what I mean :). Attach it to the door, and log the values as you open the door. From that, you'll see which values are important to detect a door opening. A door opens in a circle. I would imagine the x and y co-ordinates would be following a sinusoidal path from closed to open

Comment: Alternatively, it might be enough to check that the change of *any* of the axes past a certain threshold is enough to detect the door opened, since it's usually stationary

Comment: It doesn't seem as though circular motion effects the readings to the accelerometer at all. All 3 values stay closely the same when the accel is in any vertical orientation. It only seems like vertical or horizontal flipping affects the values, but not any form of spinning motion (similar to the motion of a spinning top but slower of course)

Comment: You have understood, that an accelerometer is sensing the change of forces and not the position? The only positional chance you can sense directly is the alignment of the gravity force relativly to the axyses. Unluckily that does not change since a door turns around the direction of gravity. So, you can sense the movement only and it depending on how fastly the door is opened the values might be very different.

Answer (score 2):

With your current code it depends on how the accelerometer is oriented with respect to the door.

One possible solution is to determine the length of the acceleration vector. That should work in any orientation;

```
axes = adxl345.getAxes(True)
accel = math.sqrt(axes['x']**2 + axes['y']**2 + axes['z']**2)
```

If you're not interested in the actual value, you *might* get away with just summing the components;

```
accel = axes['x'] + axes['y'] + axes['z']
```

But in this case it *could* happen that a positive acceleration on one axis is cancelled out by a negative acceleration on another axis! And you'd have to test for a value both larger than the threshold and smaller than the negative value of the threshold.

**Edit**:

According to the [datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL345.pdf), the ADXL345 is a three-axis accelerometer. That by itself can *not* detect rotations!
To detect rotations, you'll need a combination of an accelerometer and gyroscope, like the [MPU-6050](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10937).

A *possible* way to get around this would be to fasten the accelerometer to the edge of the door opposite the hinges. That way it would experience the most linear acceleration when the door is opened. But the accelleration of an opening door is pretty low. It could be that it is below the detection threshold of this sensor, especially when the door is opened slowly.

A much better way to detect the opening of a door is to put a switch attached to the pi's input pins between the door and frame on the handle side. Even a small opening of the door would activate the switch.

Comment: Currently the accelerometer is oriented so the arrow labeled x is pointing directly up on the back of the accelerometer.

Comment: If you can make it work in any orientation, you don't have to worry about the orientation of the sensor. Make sure to put your acceleration sensor on the side of the door handle, not on the side of the hinges.

Comment: After many tests now my accelerometer, for whatever reason, just does not detect any changes from circular motions. All 3 axes remain the same no matter how I move the door once it is attached. The only changes it will pick up are when the orientation goes from laying flat horizontally on a table to standing vertically.

Comment: Where have you attached it to the door?